# Linking failure of a program with templated main

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, lnk2019

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

I can compile my program, but can't run it. It's a windows console application, and it's set as such in `Linker -> System -> SubSystem`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include "puzzle.h"
#include "state.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Puzzle, typename State>
int main()
{
    Puzzle puzzle8;
    State goalState = new State();
    State currentState = new State();

    //goal state
    goalState.board = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                        { 4, 5, 6 },
                        { 7, 8, 0 } };
    //start state
    currentState.board = { { 8, 2, 1 },
                            { 5, 6, 0 },
                            { 3, 7, 4 } };

    puzzle8.visited.push_back(currentState); //add to visited

    while (!isGoalState(currentState, goalState))
    {           
        int f, best;
        int board1Cost, board2Cost, board3Cost, board4Cost;
        vector<State> newStates = expand(currentState);
        int bestState = getLowestCost(newStates);

        currentState = newStates.at(bestState).board;
        cout << "New State found:" << endl;
        printState(currentState);
        puzzle8.visited.push_back(currentState);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot template `main`. It needs to be a very boring, very ordinary function.

It's not clear why the template part is even there. I think the mistake is having that line, it should be removed, as `State` and `Puzzle` should be defined in their respective header files which you correctly include.

Remember `template` functions don't actually generate any compiled code unless they're used, and then the compiler will generate code releavant to the types involved. Since this template is declared and never used it's basically ignored.

Comment: You are correct. I removed it and it worked. Thanks!